# Last-Modified header is changed, even if the resource hasn't changed

Tags: 7, caching

Unless I'm mistaken, Drupal is changing the "Last-Modified" HTTP header for a page any time the page cache is regenerated - even if the raw content remains identical.  This means that clients end up having to re-download exactly the same information any time the page cache is regenerated even for pages that have not changed at all.

I realize that I can improve this situation by trying to engineer things such that the page caches are not regenerated unless the resource has changed, but is there any way I can set things up such that the Last-Modified header genuinely reflects whether or not the content has changed?  This would seem to me to be a more robust solution.

Comment: I should add - I have a similar issue with Etags.  I would like to use them to identify whether or not the resource has changed, but it seems that Drupal treats these completely differently to how I would like too.

Answer (score 2):

The code that is causing the issues you're describing lives in [drupal_serve_page_from_cache()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_serve_page_from_cache/7). Instead of using a hash of the contents of the cache; Drupal uses the `$cache->created` value. Looking over everything hacking core is the only option at the moment. I'll see if there can be a way of not hacking core if one has total control of the cache backend; if there is a way look for an update inside of https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers which will be delivered for newly rendered as well as responses retrieved from the page cache from within `hook_boot`. However, it might end up being rather challenging to determine the true modification date of any resource at this point in the request/response cycle (think of changes in other regions than the main content, e.g. blocks, panel panes, ...).

Also keep in mind that `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers are only useful for *bandwith optimization*. This is extremely important for large static assets (images, CSS, JavaScript) but its generally not worth the hassle when delivering markup.

While I do not recommend it, you actually can override those headers from within a `hook_boot()` implementation in a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_boot()
 */
function MYMODULE_boot() {
  drupal_add_http_header('Last-Modified', 'Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
  drupal_add_http_header('ETag', 'abcdefg');
}
```